# How can I make the pagination buttons work using belongsto and hasmany relationship?

Tags: laravel, pagination

There seems to be no error when clicking the button but it doesn't redirect me to `page=2`, I tried right clicking it and opening it to another tab and it works just fine. I also tried using it with ajax but the problem is the button, it won't go to page 2.

Controller

```
$decryptedID = Crypt::decrypt($id); //decryps the encrypted id
        $comments = Articles::where('id',$decryptedID)->where('slug',$slug)->first()->with('comments')->paginate(5,['*'],'comments');
        return view('articles.article',compact(['comments']))->render();
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/news/article/{id}/{slug}','Admin\ArticlesController@show')
        ->where('slug','[\w\d\-\_]+')
        ->name('articles');
```

here's an example of the http link:
`/news/article/37/Test-Image-Upload-Summernote`

View

```
<div class="row comments">
            @foreach ($comments as $comment )
                <div class="card mt-1 border-0">
                    <div class="card-body comment">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="d-inline-block">
                                <strong class="user-name">{{ $comment->name}}</strong>
                                <span class="text-muted user-time">• {{ $comment->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-comment">{{ $comment->comment }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="row mt-3">
                {!!  $comments->links() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: First of all, why do you need to encrypt the id?

Comment: It was to hide the value of the id, but found out that it was not a good practice to encrypt the id in the view.

Comment: It absolutely is not the right way to go. If you want to hide the contents of your db from guess work, implement uuid4 instead.

Comment: I already have a uuid on my database. I will try working it out later. I'm still confused on why my pagination buttons aren't working.

Comment: Internally Laravel pagination creates its own routes that it uses, I am suspecting that route is does not decrypt your id.

Comment: I already removed the encryption and decryption of my id. My problem is the buttons doesn't work but right clicking it or adding `?page=2` to it works just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243555/discussion-between-prog-24-and-play-free).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this belong to relationship.

```
Comments::with('article')->whereHas('article',function($query) use($article_id){
```

$query->where('id',$article_id);
})->paginate (5);

**Comments.php**

public function article(){

return $this->belongs to(Comments::class);
}

Comment: Hi, it seems the problem was with my stupidness using encrypt to my id in my blade.  I have resolve this issue earlier. Thank you so much